# Using modulus operator in C produce some strange result

Tags: c, operators

How to make modulus operation in C language?

Please read my code below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{       
    int i = 100;

    printf("%d\n", i%100);
    printf("%d\n", i%240);
    printf("%d\n", i%40);
    printf("%d\n", i%10);


    return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
$ ./modulus
0
100
20
0
```

Please tell me how to use it correctly.

## EDIT

Sorry I did a mistake in code. the division should come otherside like in below code.

```
printf("%d\n", 100%i);
printf("%d\n", 240%i);
printf("%d\n", 40%i);
printf("%d\n", 10%i);
```

What I was expecting was to get the `0` when the value is multiplication of 100;

I am sorry for the mistake. But guys, please undo my downvotes.

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: You're using it correctly.

Comment: what output you want. because your program is correct.

Comment: `How to make modulus operation in C language?` As per you already used :)

Comment: @MarounMaroun no not correct: ["modulus and remainder are not the same"](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/modulus-remainder)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to code a modulo (%) operator in C/C++/Obj-C that handles negative numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003232/how-to-code-a-modulo-operator-in-c-c-obj-c-that-handles-negative-numbers)

Comment: It was a mistake in code. I was expecting to get `0` when the multiplication of 100 is reached.

Answer (score 1):

The result of a [modulo division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is the remainder of an [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html) of the given numbers ( on the positive scale).

That means:

```
100 / 100 = 1, remainder 0
=> 100 mod 100 = 0

100 / 240 = 0, remainder 100
=> 100 mod 240 = 100

100 / 40 = 2, remainder 20
=> 100 mod 40 = 20

100 / 10 = 10, remainder 0
=> 100 mod 10 = 0
```

Comment: *"The result of a modulo division is the remainder of an integer division of the given numbers."* ---> [modulus and remainder are not the same](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/modulus-remainder)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan - Thanks :-) - added `on the positive scale`

Comment: Add trick for [negative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19264015/modulo-of-a-negative-number)  also, Check related Q&A also I am not sure that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it works correctly. What have you expected to see?

Modulos operator (the implementation of the modulo operation), gets you the division remainder. For example:

```
a % b = c
```

Can be rewritten as a = b * d + c, where a, b, c, d are integers.

So, 100 % 40 = 20 because 100 = 40 * 2 + 20

Answer (score 0):

the output you are getting is correct. The modulus operator returns the remainder when you perform integer division of two numbers.

In your case

- 100 mod 100 = 0   as 100 = 100*1 + **0**
- 100 mod 240 = 100 as 100 = 240*0 + **100**
- 100 mod 40 = 20   as 100 = 40*2 + **20**
- 100 mod 10 = 10   as 100 = 10*10 + **0**

Hope it helps :)